# Can't find symbol 'JTextField' in Java

Tags: java, swing, compilation, jtextfield

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     JButton jbtOK = new JButton("OK");
     JButton jbtCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
     JLabel jlblName = new JLabel("Enter your name: ");
     JTextField jtfName = JTextField("Type Name Here");
     JCheckBox jchkBold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
     JCheckBox jchkItalic = new JCheckBox("Italic");
     JRadioButton jrbRed = new JRadioButton("Red");
     JRadioButton jrbYellow = new JRadioButton("Red");
     JComboBox jcboColor = new JComboBox(new String[] {"Freshman",
       "Sophmore", "Junior", "Senior"});
     JPanel panel = new JPanel();
     panel.add(jbtOK);
     panel.add(jbtCancel);
     panel.add(jlblName);
     panel.add(jtfName);
     panel.add(jchkBold);
     panel.add(jchkItalic);
     panel.add(jrbRed);
     panel.add(jrbYellow);
     panel.add(jcboColor);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setTitle("Show GUI Components");
    frame.setSize(450, 100);
    frame.setLocation(200, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**The output that I get when I tried to compile**

```
gurbhej@Nanda:~/Dropbox/Programming/Java Programs/Test$ javac Test.java 
Test.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
JTextField jtfName = JTextField("Type Name Here");
                     ^
symbol:   method JTextField(String)
location: class Test
Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
gurbhej@Nanda:~/Dropbox/Programming/Java Programs/Test$
```

I got this example from a book and also didn't find anything from Errata.
Why am I getting this error? This is my first time with GUI stuff in Java so I have no idea how to fix this. Does the JTextField even exits in the Java libraries or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Notice anything different about that line compared to all the other ones?

Comment: JTextField jtfName = new JTextField("Type Name Here");

Comment: @Brian Roach: Maybe I should stop using Notepad now :)

Comment: LOL. Yes. Yes you should. (Don't feel bad, we've all been there)

Comment: LOL, @JavaNoob I am still using TextPad :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forget `new` before `JTextField`, so the code will be :

```
JTextField jtField = new JTextField("");
```